# Matrix exponentiation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to exponentiate a complex matrix in Python and am running into some trouble. I'm using the `scipy.linalg.expm` function, and am having a rather strange error message when I try the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

hamiltonian = np.mat('[1,0,0,0;0,-1,0,0;0,0,-1,0;0,0,0,1]')

# This works
t_list = np.linspace(0,1,10)
unitary = [linalg.expm(-(1j)*t*hamiltonian) for t in t_list]

# This doesn't
t_list = np.linspace(0,10,100)
unitary = [linalg.expm(-(1j)*t*hamiltonian) for t in t_list]
```

The error when the second experiment is run is:

```
This works!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrix_exp.py", line 11, in <module>
    unitary_t = [linalg.expm(-1*t*(1j)*hamiltonian) for t in t_list]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/matfuncs.py",     line 105, in expm
    return scipy.sparse.linalg.expm(A)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist- packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 344, in expm
    X = _fragment_2_1(X, A, s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-  packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 462, in _fragment_2_1
    X[k, k] = exp_diag[k]
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

This seems really strange since all I changed was the range of `t` I was using. Is it because the Hamiltonian is diagonal? In general, the Hamiltonians won't be, but I also want it to work for diagonal ones. I don't really know the mechanics of `expm`, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try moving the calculation to a for loop instead of a list comprehension. Then you could at least figure out which value of t it's failing on.

Comment: The first number that the program fails on is `t=2.12121212121`. It seems totally arbitrary ... the program does not work for `t=2.ax` where `a > 0`. And it doesn't work for `t=3.x` at all ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is interesting. One thing I can say is that the problem is specific to the `np.matrix` subclass. For example, the following works fine:

```
h = np.array(hamiltonian)
unitary = [linalg.expm(-(1j)*t*h) for t in t_list]
```

---

Digging a little deeper into the traceback, the exception is being raised in `_fragment_2_1` in `scipy.sparse.linalg.matfuncs.py`, specifically [these lines](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/81c096001974f0b5efe29ec83b54f725cc681540/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py#L748-L755):

```
n = X.shape[0]
diag_T = T.diagonal().copy()

# Replace diag(X) by exp(2^-s diag(T)).
scale = 2 ** -s
exp_diag = np.exp(scale * diag_T)
for k in range(n):
    X[k, k] = exp_diag[k]
```

The error message

```
    X[k, k] = exp_diag[k]
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

suggests to me that `exp_diag[k]` ought to be a scalar, but is instead returning a vector (and you can't assign a vector to `X[k, k]`, which is a scalar).

Setting a breakpoint and examining the shapes of these variables confirms this:

```
ipdb> l
    751     # Replace diag(X) by exp(2^-s diag(T)).
    752     scale = 2 ** -s
    753     exp_diag = np.exp(scale * diag_T)
    754     for k in range(n):
    755         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()  # breakpoint e86ebbd4 //
--> 756         X[k, k] = exp_diag[k]
    757 
    758     for i in range(s-1, -1, -1):
    759         X = X.dot(X)
    760 
    761         # Replace diag(X) by exp(2^-i diag(T)).

ipdb> exp_diag.shape
(1, 4)
ipdb> exp_diag[k].shape
(1, 4)
ipdb> X[k, k].shape
()
```

The underlying problem is that `exp_diag` is assumed to be either 1D or a column vector, but the diagonal of an `np.matrix` object is a row vector. This highlights a more general point that `np.matrix` is generally less well-supported than `np.ndarray`, so in most cases it's better to use the latter.

One possible solution would be to use `np.ravel()` to flatten `diag_T` into a 1D `np.ndarray`:

```
diag_T = np.ravel(T.diagonal().copy())
```

This seems to fix the problem you're encountering, although there may be other issues relating to `np.matrix` that I haven't spotted yet.

---

I've opened a pull request [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5867).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I think I may just work with `ndarray` instead of `mat` and cast things back to matrices at the end if I need to. I guess I don't know enough about the internal workings of the two classes.

Unrelated, but how do you set breakpoints in Python? Are you using a particular IDE or can you do it in `emacs`, etc.?

Comment: You don't need an IDE to set breakpoints. I'm using [`ipdb`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb), but you can also use the standard Python debugger, `pdb`. I use SublimeText3 as an editor which has an extension for conveniently setting breakpoints, but there's bound to be an Emacs equivalent...